# code terminated once exception caught java

Tags: java, exception

I was expecting remaining code to continue even after throwing exception for some products. Please find my code below.

```
public class Example1 {

    void productCheck(int[] weight) throws InvalidProductException {

        for (int i = 0; i < weight.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Product -->"+weight[i]);
            if (weight[i] < 100) {
                System.out.println("Product exception-->"+weight[i]);
                throw new InvalidProductException("Product Invalid");
            }
        }

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Example1 obj = new Example1();
        
        int[] weight = {110, 60, 10, 20, 100, 60 };
        try {
            obj.productCheck(weight);
            
        } catch (InvalidProductException ex) {
            System.out.println("Caught the exception for Product");
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        } 
    }

}

public class InvalidProductException extends Exception
    {
public InvalidProductException(String s)
    {
    // Call constructor of parent Exception
    super(s);
    }
}
```

Output :

```
Product -->110
Product -->60
Product exception-->60
Caught the exception for Product
Product Invalid
```

Comment: You don't catch the exception in a loop, so, yes, it will terminate after the exception is caught.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The control breaks out of the `for` loop as soon as the exception occurs. If you wanted the loop to continue, then each `try-catch` should be present to handle each `weight`. Otherwise, you could capture all the erroneous weights and then throw a single exception. You could refactor the code as:

```java
void productCheck(int[] weight) throws InvalidProductException {
    List<Integer> errors = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < weight.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Product -->"+weight[i]);
        if (weight[i] < 100) {
            errors.add(Integer.valueOf(weight[i]));
        }
    }
    if(!errors.isEmpty()){
        System.out.println("Product exception for weights -->"+errors);
        throw new InvalidProductException("Product Invalid");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

As Andy stated your try catch is outside the scope of the for loop there for the productCheck method is exited when the exception is thrown and continues up the stack until it is caught in the main method. If you wish the productCheck to continue the for loop after you throw the exception the try catch must be located inside the for loop. See below.

```
public class Example1 {

void productCheck(int[] weight) throws InvalidProductException {

    for (int i = 0; i < weight.length; i++) {
        try {

            System.out.println("Product -->"+weight[i]);
            if (weight[i] < 100) {
                System.out.println("Product exception-->"+weight[i]);
                throw new InvalidProductException("Product Invalid");
            }
        } catch (InvalidProductException ex) {
            System.out.println("Caught the exception for Product");
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }     
    }

}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    Example1 obj = new Example1();
    
    int[] weight = {110, 60, 10, 20, 100, 60 };
    obj.productCheck(weight);
}

}
public class InvalidProductException extends Exception
    {
public InvalidProductException(String s)
    {
    // Call constructor of parent Exception
    super(s);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are throwing the exception at method level, it will anyway terminate.

One the exception is thrown, it will terminate the execution there itself and the exception will be caught in the try-catch block in the main method.

SUGGESTED SOLUTION:

Extract the loop outside of the method and put it in another method or the main method and add try-catch block inside the loop.

OR

Handle the error there itself instead of throwing exception.